# How do i enable websockets in xmpp openfire server

Tags: websocket, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I am developing real time chat application in my website.For that i want to use websockets for communication.And i am using openfire server but i dont know how to enable websockets in openfire server . Any ideas.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you use OpenFire 3.10 use this sources for compile a fixed version of websocket.
https://code.google.com/p/openfire-websockets/source/detail?r=21
(not tested, trying to find a way to compile it under linux)

You can download websocket build here;
https://code.google.com/p/openfire-websockets/downloads/list
Load plugin in you Web Admin Interface (.war is same of .jar)

Google a little bit and you can found some informations for OpenFire 3.7.2 and compatible version of websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Igniterealtime Anounces a plugin

[Openfire WebSocket Plugin Readme](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/websocket/readme.html)

Please go through the above readme